Is this sum of limits proof valid?
It seems to me that something is not correct about this proof of sum of limits. This is a proof that is repeated in numerous places in textbooks and throughout the internet. I will include the whole proof here.
https://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/math111/proofs/limitOfSum/
A problem seems to arise when the proof arrives at the point where the individual limits of $|f(x)-L_1|$ and $|g(x)-L_2|$ are arbitrarily defined as $< \epsilon/2$ and that $\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.
The proof states:
$$\text{if} \quad 0<|x−c|<\delta, \quad \text{then} \quad |f(x)−L_1|< \epsilon/2 \quad \text{and} \quad |g(x)−L_2|<\epsilon/2$$
and
$$\text{if} \quad 0<|x−c|<\delta, \quad \text{then} \quad |f(x)−L_1|+|g(x)−L_2|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon.$$
We are told that in order to create this case, we have to choose the lower of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.
Then we can use the triangle inequality for absolute values (i.e. $|A+B|\leq|A|+|B|$) to discover:
$$\text{if} \quad 0<|x−c|<\delta, \quad \text{then} \quad |f(x)−L_1+g(x)−L_2|\leq|f(x)−L_1|+|g(x)−L_2|<\epsilon.$$
The problem with this is that if the value for $\epsilon$ is to have any reference point at all, it must be from the original definition of the limit.
$$\text{if} \quad 0<|x−c|<\delta, \quad \text{then} \quad |(f(x)+g(x))−(L_1+L_2)|<\epsilon.$$
But in that case, the $\delta$ value was larger than the $\delta_1$ value we now have. Remember that we had to use the smaller $\delta_1$ value, which is less than the original $\delta$, in order to bring the two parts $|f(x)−L_1|$ and $|g(x)−L_2|$ each below $\epsilon/2$.
So, yes, we can say:
$$|f(x)−L_1+g(x)−L_2| \leq |f(x)−L_1|+|g(x)−L_2|<\epsilon,$$
and therefore
$$|f(x)−L_1+g(x)−L_2| < \epsilon$$
but only if we take $0<|x−c|<\delta_1$, where $\delta_1$ is less than $\delta$.
It seems that $\delta$ was switched out for $\delta_1$ without it being acknowledged.
We can say $|(f(x)+g(x))−(L_1+L_2)|<\epsilon$ if $0<|x−c|<\delta_1$, but it seems we still do not know if it is true when $0<|x−c|<\delta$. Therefore, the sum law would not been proven.
Am I missing something here? If so, can someone show me the error?

What is “the original $\delta$”?

The original delta is the delta value that was used in the first framing of the problem.  If 0<|x−c|<δ, then |(f(x)+g(x))−(L1+L2)|<ϵ.  The proof said it uses a lower value for delta δ1 so that the two parts can  each <ϵ/2.

sorry I don't know what latex is

It seems we would have to show that the epsilon delta relationship holds for that value of delta for the proof to be valid.

Please edit your posted question, using MathJax to replace all math expressions.  Also, having skimmed your posted question, it is unclear to me how you are defining $~\delta_1.$

$\delta = \min {\delta_1 , \delta_2}$ so it can't be true that $\delta > \delta_1$.

Yes =min{1,2} so they have switched in δ1  and created a new value for delta. What was the original ? It was the value of delta that made this statement true: 0<|x−c|<δ, then |(f(x)+g(x))−(L1+L2)|<ϵ . Epsilon and delta have a relationship with each other, when delta decreases so does epsilon in a particular way for a given limit. The proof took the the epsilon from that definition as its value for epsilon because that was what it is trying to prove.  Then it said that each part of the triangle inequality was less than ϵ/2.  In order to do than it lowered  to 1.

You get to choose $\delta$ based on $\epsilon$. Here the choice is $\delta = \min {\delta_1 ,\delta_2}$. As long as that choice works the proof works.

Note that the definition of limit has quantified variables and thes variables are specializable to (somewhat arbitrary) expressions (satisfying the conditions we explicitly place on them).
$$  \forall \Delta y > 0, \exists \Delta x \text{ such that } |x-c| < \Delta x \implies |f(x) - L| < \Delta y  $$
One may start a proof "Let $\varepsilon > 0.$" and then proceed to specialize the definition of limit to both
$$  \forall \varepsilon/2 > 0, \exists \delta_1 \text{ such that } 0 < |x-c| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L_1| < \varepsilon/2  $$
and
$$  \forall \varepsilon/2 > 0, \exists \delta_2 \text{ such that } 0 < |x-c| < \delta_2 \implies |g(x) - L_2| < \varepsilon/2  \text{.}  $$
Then $\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ is the minimum of a finite set of positive reals so exists and is positive.  Then we may choose $\delta \in (0, \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\})$.  Then $0<|x-c| < \delta$ implies both $0 < |x-c| < \delta_1$ and $0 < |x-c| < \delta_2$.
So $0<|x-c|<\delta$ implies both $|f(x) - L_1| < \varepsilon/2$ and $|g(x)- L_2| < \varepsilon/2$.  Then finish with the triangle inequality.

Added following comments:
The goal of some writers is to land exactly on the definition of limit:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta \text{ such that } 0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon  \text{.}  $$
The choice of specializations to $\varepsilon/2$ ensure that we end up with $|(f(x) + g(x)) - (L_1 + L_2)| \leq \dots \text{triangle inequality manipulation} < \varepsilon$ on the nose.  One may split as $\varepsilon/3$ and $2\varepsilon/3$ and still land on $\varepsilon$ on the nose.
Of course, getting $\varepsilon$ on the nose is not actually required, except for students who are just learning how everything works.  After "Let $\varepsilon > 0$." one can arrive at $|f(x) - L| < 8 \varepsilon$ and still have proven the limit.  What one cannot do is any of

$|f(x) - L| < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon/n$,
$|f(x) - L| < (x-c)^2/\delta$,
et c.

because these admit an arbitrarily large jump discontinuity at $x = c$.  If one lands on $\dots < \varepsilon$ on the nose, one can be sure to not have a circular dependency (e.g., in the definition, $\delta$ can be a function of $\varepsilon$, but not vice versa).

It seems to me if there is no "original"  and we can choose epsilon and delta to be what we want them to be then we don't need the part of the proof that involves /2.  We could say:  |()−1|< A.  and |()−2|<B when 0<|−|<. And:  |()−1| + |()−2| < A + B = C =  .   We can call C  epsilon because we can set it at whatever value we want. Then we could expand this using the triangle inequality to get |()−1+()−2|≤|()−1|+|()−2|<   when
0<|−|<
I don't know if this is a sufficient proof of the sum of limits but it doesn't seem so

It does't seem like a proof because the term  |()−1+()−2| is less than or equal to and not merely equal to |()−1|+|()−2| and we are trying to prove that the limit of the sum of the functions is equal to the sum of the limits.  It seems to me that this did not seem like a proof to whoever created the proof because they felt the need to invoke this other part where: |()−1|</2 and    |()−2|</2 where ∈(0,min{1,2}).  To do this they began with what they wanted to prove |(()+())−(1+2)|< when  0<|−|<.

To do this they began with what they wanted to prove |(()+())−(1+2)|< when 0<|−|<.  Then it appears that the intention of the proof is to insert           |()−1|+|()−2| between  |(()+())−(1+2)| and it's  by making                |()−1|</2 and |()−2|</2 by choosing a lower value for  called 1. It still seems to me that this cannot be done because the "original" delta value in the statement |(()+())−(1+2)|< when 0<|−|< has been swapped out for 1

The   is a predefined   that corresponds to a specific    and belongs to the statement |(()+())−(1+2)|<. If  was not already defined what would be the need of dividing it by two?

@Dex : I'll add a bit more.

Thanks for your answer.  From what I can understand then the part of the proof where |()−1|</2 and we choose the smaller of two deltas is not needed and could accomplished by something like |()−1|< A and |()−1| + |()−2| < A + B = C =

Thanks for your answer.  From what I can understand then the part of the proof where |()−1|</2 and we choose the smaller of two deltas is not needed and could accomplished by something like|()−1|< A and                                            |()−1| + |()−2| < A + B = C =  given some delta. Do you think this is the case?  If not why is the /2 part of the proof needed? You mentioned that they were trying to end up with the proof "on the nose" but it seems that  the /2 manipulation is still not  on the nose because we have to choose the smaller of two deltas.

@Dax76 : Of course you have to choose the smaller of two deltas to land "on the nose".  If you name that smaller delta "$\delta$", then you land on the definition of limit on the nose.  Are these stylistic choice required?  No.  Are they a good idea for students who may have trouble seeing that they have (correctly) arrived at the definition?  Yes.  They also signify that you understand how many steps along triangle inequalities you are going to need to assemble the correct inequality.

The point of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof is that we choose $\delta$ given $\epsilon$. In this case, we chose $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$.  There is no other "original" $\delta$ that you seem to be talking about; the original $\delta$ is $\min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$.

But if there is no original delta then what is epsilon and why did we need to show that we could get below it?  If epsilon is just an arbitrary number then of course we could get below it by lowering delta as much as we want.  For the proof to make sense epsilon would have to correspond to a specific delta value to begin with.  In order to show that both halves of the triangle inequality were less than </2 they had to choose a lower . The original delta would be somewhere between 1 and 2 unless both limits and functions were the same.

Your statement that "of course we could get below it by lowering delta as much as we want" is just a (very confident) restatement that the limit exists. This is the definition, and like all definitions, it's sometimes useful to consider a *non-*example. Such a situation would involve an expression/function whose values are not that close to one another no matter how close the inputs get, e.g., use a step function with $\epsilon$ smaller than the size of the step.

It seems to me if there is no "original"  and we can choose epsilon and delta to be what we want them to be then we don't need the part of the proof that involves /2. We could say: |()−1|< A. and |()−2|<B when 0<|−|<. And: |()−1| + |()−2| < A + B = C =  . We can call C epsilon because we can set it at whatever value we want. Then we could expand this using the triangle inequality to get |()−1+()−2|≤|()−1|+|()−2|< when 0<|−|< I don't know if this is a sufficient proof of the sum of limits but it doesn't seem so

It does't seem like a proof because the term |()−1+()−2| is less than or equal to and not merely equal to |()−1|+|()−2| and we are trying to prove that the limit of the sum of the functions is equal to the sum of the limits. It seems to me that this did not seem like a proof to whoever created the original proof because they felt the need to invoke this other part where: |()−1|</2 and |()−2|</2 where ∈(0,min{1,2}). To do this they began with what they wanted to prove |(()+())−(1+2)|< when 0<|−|<.

To do this they began with what they wanted to prove |(()+())−(1+2)|< when 0<|−|<. Then it appears that the intention of the proof is to insert |()−1|+|()−2| between |(()+())−(1+2)| and it's  by making |()−1|</2 and |()−2|</2 by choosing a lower value for  called 1. It still seems to me that this cannot be done because the "original" delta value in the statement |(()+())−(1+2)|< when 0<|−|< has been swapped out for 1

The  is a predefined  that corresponds to a specific  and belongs to the statement |(()+())−(1+2)|<. If  was not already defined in relation to another statement what would be the need of dividing it by two?
